# Handle Closing WPF window with [X] button and a normal button in one single sub

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm handling window closing using the red [X] button in WPF/VB.NET like this :

```
Private Sub Window_Closing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closing
    If MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous vraiment fermer l'outil ?", "FT_SOFT", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) = MessageBoxResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

And I have a "Close" button inside the window that is handled in this sub :

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles mniQuitter.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous vraiment fermer l'outil ?", "FT_SOFT", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) = MessageBoxResult.Yes Then
        RemoveHandler MyBase.Closing, AddressOf Window_Closing
        MyBase.Close()
    End If
End sub
```

The line `RemoveHandler MyBase.Closing, AddressOf Window_Closing` prevents the first sub from being called when the close button is clicked, because otherwise, you would get two MessageBoxes.

I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this, by calling the first sub inside the second sub, but the `e` argument type doesn't match (obviously). How can this be done ?

Comment: did you try only `MyBase.Close()` in `MenuItem_Click`, without MessageBox and RemoveHandler ?

Comment: I can't take the MsgBox away. EDIT : You're actually right.

Comment: i expect that when you call `MyBase.Close()` from `MenuItem_Click` the next event will be `Window_Closing` and MessageBox appear from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only call `MyBase.Close()` from `MenuItem_Click`

```
Private Sub MenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles mniQuitter.Click
    MyBase.Close()
End sub
```

the next event will be `Window_Closing` and MessageBox will appear from there